# Calculate Average of data by different sub groups

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, vb.net

I have no code as example as yet, just wondering best way to go about this.

I am using vb2010 and have a datatable where I need to display the averages by different sub groups.

i.e.

[image: Example]

I need to calculate the average for all names and then average for groups as well (status)

This is just example, I can have many different Status.

Data is loaded from SQL server into a dataadapter in VB2010 by date range, and I currently use datagridview to show all rows.

There are a lot of other columns in dataset.

not sure on best method to get desired result, help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first grouping you should be able to use:

```
Select
   [Name],
   [Status],
   avg(Score) over (partition by [Status], [Name] order by (select null))
from table
group by 
   [Name],
   [Status]
```

And for the total average:

```
avg(Score) over (partition by [Status] order by (select null))
```

You should also be able to accomplish this with a conditional aggregation.

```
avg(case when [Name] = 'Fred' and [Status] = 'Accepted' then Score end) as FredAcceptedAvg,
avg(case when [Name] = 'Ian' and [Status] = 'Accepted' then Score end) as FredAcceptedAvg,
avg(case when [Name] = 'Fred' and [Status] = 'Declined' then Score end) as FredDeclinedAvg,
avg(case when [Name] = 'Ian' and [Status] = 'Declined' then Score end) as IanDeclinedAvg,
avg(case when [Status] = 'Declined' then Score end) as DeclinedAvg,
avg(case when [Status] = 'Accepted' then Score end) as AcceptedAvg
```

Then you can display this however and where ever you want.

Comment: ..`order by (select null)` is not needed in the window function.

Comment: Thank you, I think I need to exlpain a little more, how would I accomplish this if I dident know what he Status code was or Names, reason is that depending on how datatable is filled it can have different names/status  is there a way to look through the table to achieve this, I am complete novice with SQL and only really a little more than a beginner with VB, but I do understand what you have provided just not how to implement for myself

Comment: Use the top method then

Comment: Thank you, had to make slight mod to work SQL 2005                                `code` Select distinct
   [Agent],
   [Status],
   avg(Score) over (partition by [Status], [Agent]) as AvgScore
from [QA_Scorecards].[dbo].[tbl_Entrys]
group by 
   [Agent],
   [Status],
   [Score]
order by [Status] `code`

Comment: I added above comment incorrect format, and due to reboot have been able to change layout, also how do I make the AVG show upto 1 decimal place please

Comment: Use cast(score as decimal(16,1)) inside the case statement

Comment: Cheers, but I'm using the select over partion method which works best for me, I have tried convert and cast but cant seem to get right placment in select, I can only get as far as lets say 97.753333 by doing Select distinct [Status],
   AVG (convert(decimal(16,1),Score)) over (partition by [Status]) as ScoreAVG